# Getting XPATH from table in webpage

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2012, xpath

I have the following xpath: `/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a`

from:

```
<div id="search-result-block">
<div class="">
<table class="search-result" width="100%">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="result-num">
    <td class="result-header" colspan="2">
      <a class="srtitle" href="http://books.ioba.org/books/4359746.html">1001 Designs for     Whittling and Woodcarving</a>
      <br>
      <div class="srauthor">Tangerman, Elmer John </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and I need to get the inner html of that xpath, however my application is giving me a null exception (i guess it is finding that the path is wrong or something)

Here is my current code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode rootNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode;
titleBook = rootNode.SelectSingleNode(@".//table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a").InnerHtml.ToString();
```

I tried using `@"//table[contains(@class, 'result-header')]/a"` instead but still did not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried td[1]?

Answer (score 1):

All in all, I believe the easiest way to select your node is

```
//a[@class='srtitle']
```

But your HTML is really messy... Missing some matching tags, for example, which will render the behavior non-predictable.

Your first path doesn't work because the two `td` seem to be actually nested, not siblings: it should be `@"//table/tbody/tr/td/td/a"`.

The second xpath could be simplified and fixed with `@"//td[@class="result-header']/a`, or if you want `@"//td[contains(@class, 'result-header')]/a"`.

Comment: Great, that worked however I would like to know how I can understand the xpath since I have the same problems with other websites that use tables. Any help or link is appreciated! :)

Comment: `[..]` is used to put a condition: it will match the node only if the condition is fulfilled. They are many tuto online if you want to learn more!

Comment: mm. I see but the problem is getting around those tables in the web pages. I tried searching about this already but did not find any useful information :/

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you mean. If `//a[@class='srtitle']` works here, why not on other websites? `table` has nothing to do with it, the goal is to find some criteria you can build your XPath on. Here, the criteria is the class being equal to something.

Comment: well if I apply the same knowledge from this, other websites give me a null value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have your solution, but here's a LINQ-esq library for generating xpath expressions for similar situations.

http://www.unit-testing.net/CurrentArticle/How-to-Create-Xpath-From-Lambda-Expressions.html